# Traveling abroad with encryption software on my computer

Tags: encryption, legal

I have software installed on my computer that has encryption capabilities. This is the case both for things like VPN/SSL, and also GPG. I don't really use GPG (there are not that many people I can use it with), but I have it in case I want to send sensitive information of one kind or another. I know that the US has export control laws about encryption software - should I be concerned about taking my computer with me abroad, if I have software installed on my computer that includes encryption capabilities, even if I don't plan on using it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting legal advice, which is best obtained from a qualified legal practitioner in an appropriate jurisdiction.